# Alarm keeps triggering after set time

Tags: android

could you please have a look at this

```
if(current.getTimeInMillis() < cal.getTimeInMillis()){
      //current.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
      alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, current.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
      Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm will go of 15mins from now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }else {
       alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + cal.getTimeInMillis() + " seconds",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

current.getTimeInMillis() is the system time and cal.getTimeInMillis() is a set time that i want an event to occur. i am trying to make an alarm every 15 mins as long as the system time is not greater than the designated set time and when the set time has reached, the alarm should go off. but my problem is, it keeps repeating every 15 minutes even after the past set time and it completely ignores the code in the else block.Am i doing the logic incorrectly?.. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is unclear about `alarms.SETREPEATING(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, current.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);`

Comment: what i meant was that, even after the designated set time(cal.getTimeInMillis()) has elaspsed, the alarm still keeps triggering. which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: setREPEATING means it will continue to fire the alarm over and over...  You've got it scheduled to go off every 15 minutes, over and over and over, until you cancel it.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. i thought it would go off since it was inside a boolean logic. Thanks again